# PowerShell: Copy-Item throws DriveNotFoundException

Tags: exception, powershell, copy-item

My script keeps bugging me with the following exception

```
copy-item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'F' does not exist.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\ARCserve Backup\Templates\RB_Pre_Process.ps1:58 char:1
+ copy-item -Path $drive -Destination $DST_DRIVE -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (F:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

This is what my script looks like. I am mounting an ISO image on drive F: and I have added a "start-slepp -s 5" command so i can verify the image get's mounted, which it does!

```
$BACKUP_PATH = "E:\00_BACKUP_DATA"
$DR_PATH = "E:\01_DR_DATA"
$ISO_IMAGE = "C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\ARCserve Backup\Templates\Winpe_x64.iso"
$DST_DRIVE = "E:\"

try {
    New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "RB_Pre_Process.ps1" -ErrorAction Stop
} catch [System.InvalidOperationException] {
    Write-host $_
}

try {
    Write-Host "Preparing RDX cartridge..."

    # Query for disk object 
    $disk_number = (Get-Disk | Where-Object -Property FriendlyName -like "TANDBERG RDX*").Number

    # Remove partitions
    Get-Disk $disk_number | Clear-Disk -RemoveData -Confirm:$false | Out-Null

    # Create new partition
    New-Partition -DiskNumber $disk_number -UseMaximumSize | Out-Null

    # Format partition
    Format-Volume -DriveLetter E -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "RDX_TAPE" -Confirm:$false  | Out-Null

    # Set partition as active 
    Set-Partition -DriveLetter E -IsActive:$true | Out-Null
} catch {
    Write-Host $_
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name -EventID 2 -Message $_
}

try {
    Write-Host "Creating folder structure..."

    new-item -itemtype directory -Path $BACKUP_PATH -ErrorAction stop | Out-Null
    new-item -itemtype directory -path $DR_PATH -ErrorAction stop | Out-Null
} catch {
    Write-Host $_
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name -EventID 2 -Message $_
}

try {
    Write-Host "Mounting ISO image..."

    $image = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISO_IMAGE -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
} catch [ParameterBindingException] {
    Write-Host $_
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name -EventId 2 -Message $_
}

$drive = ($image | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
$drive += ":\*"

Start-Sleep -s 5 

try {
    Write-Host "Copying ISO content..."

    copy-item -Path $drive -Destination $DST_DRIVE -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    Write-Host $_
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name -EventId 2 -Message $_
}

try {
    Write-Host "Unmounting ISO image..."

    Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISO_IMAGE -ErrorAction Stop 
} catch [System.Exception] {
    Write-Host $_ 
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name -EventId 2 -Message $_
}
```

So, what's going wrong here? Sometimes it works sometimes not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I "solved" the issue... my script is working perfectly fine when it's getting started directly from the PowerShell prompt instead of the PowerShell ISE... So the IDE is the culprit.

Comment: Glad I found this.  Have been troubleshooting this across a few functions I'm working on.  Interestingly, .NET calls work without issue.  Couple hours down the drain :(  Anyhow, like you mentioned, no issue in the console host, so now I can either use .NET or just execute the command in a new powershell process.

Comment: I spent whole one evening figuring this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

it seems the mounted image can't be reached in powershell. I think it's a limitation of the provider. A possible workaround is issuing CMD command. You could replace

```
    copy-item -Path $drive -Destination $DST_DRIVE -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
```

with

```
& cmd /C "copy F:\* G:\dest\"
```

Here I just give an example, you may need to do further work to copy recursively..you could use the `xcopy` or `robocopy` which could handle recursive copy.